# SQLite3 on QPython on Android 6.0 not working properly

Tags: python, sqlite, qpython

Importing the SQLite3 module works at first, and creating a database or table works fine too.

But suddenly, when trying to insert something in it — Python throws an irresponsible kind of error (sometimes throws syntaxError without highlighting any line of code — seriously, there's no reason for the error).

I know SQLite3 on Android 6.0 raises issues — there are many options to solve this on Java but is there any solution for QPython (Android 6.0)?

This is my insert line:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO pins(pin) VALUES (?)", (S)
```

The above is the line python points the error to

Comment: Post the error you get with relevant lines of code.

Comment: File "/storage/emulated/0/com.hipipal.qpyplus/.last_tmp.py", line 27

             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You are missing an ending parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

1. Close the cur.execute properly
2. There is this thing with python tuples, so add a comma to the data tuple

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO pins(pin) VALUES (?)", (S,))`